# Help find my mistake in using method of characteristics to find general solution to wave-equation?

Tags: wave-equation, characteristics

I obtained sum of unidirectional waves, and not the sum of a forward and backward wave. Where did I go wrong?

---

$$u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}$$

$$\iff u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0$$

$$\iff (\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} - c \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}) [ ( \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} + c \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x})]u=0$$

$$\iff (\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} - c \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}) ( u_t+cu_x)=0$$

Assume $$v(x,t)=u_t+cu_x$$

$$(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} - c \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x})v=0$$

Then,
$$cv_x+v_t=0.$$

This may be solved for $v(x,t)$ using the method of characteristics.

Lagrange-Charpit:

$$\dfrac{dx}{c}=\dfrac{dt}{1}=\dfrac{dv}{0}$$

$$\iff x=ct+A$$

$$x-ct=A$$

$$f(x-ct)=v(x,t)=cu_x+u_t$$

It remains to solve for $u(x,t).$

Lagrange-Charpit:

$$\dfrac{dx}{c}=\dfrac{dt}{1}=\dfrac{du}{f(x-ct)}$$

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=c \implies x=ct+A \implies x-ct=A$$

$$\dfrac{du}{dt}=f(x-ct)$$

$$u(x,t)=\int f(x-ct) dt$$

$$u(x,t)=F(x-ct) + B$$ where

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} F(x-ct)=f(x-ct).$$

$$u(x,t)-F(x-ct)=B$$

$$u(x,t)=g(x-ct)+F(x-ct)$$ as $$g(A)=B$$ gives the solution.

---

But this is incorrect as we should have $$u(x,t)=h(x-ct)+p(x+ct)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I obtained sum of unidirectional waves, and not the sum of a forward and backward wave. Where did I go wrong?

---

$$u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}$$

$$\iff u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0$$

$$\iff (\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} - c \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}) [ ( \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} + c \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x})]u=0$$

$$\iff (\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} - c \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}) ( u_t+cu_x)=0$$

Assume $$v(x,t)=u_t+cu_x$$

$$(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} - c \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x})v=0$$

Then,
$$***-cv_x+v_t=0.***$$

This may be solved for $v(x,t)$ using the method of characteristics.

Lagrange-Charpit:

$$\dfrac{dx}{**-c**}=\dfrac{dt}{1}=\dfrac{dv}{0}$$

$$\iff x=-ct+A$$

$$x+ct=A$$

$$f(x+ct)=v(x,t)=cu_x+u_t$$

It remains to solve for $u(x,t).$

---

Do the rest....